# Replace ID1: Value1..........with ID1: NewValue1

Tags: c#-4.0

I used a code but getting an error i.e
Extension methods must be defined in a top level static class; `StringHelpers` is a nested class

```
namespace Figreplace2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FileInfo n = new FileInfo(textBox1.Text);

            StringBuilder newFile = new StringBuilder();

            string temp = " ";

            string[] file = File.ReadAllLines(textBox1.Text);
        }

    public static class StringHelpers
    {
        public static string Replace(this string s)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> replacements = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            //replacements.Add("ID1", "NewValue");
            replacements.Add("ID2", "NewValue2");
            // ... further replacement entries ...

            foreach (string line in file)
            {
                bool replacementMade = false;
                foreach (var replacement in replacements)
                {
                    if (line.StartsWith(replacement.Key))
                    {
                        string newString = s;
                        temp = line.Replace(string.Format("{0}   :{1}", replacement.Key, replacement.Value));

                        newFile.Append(temp + "\r\n");

                        continue;
                        return newString;
                    }
                    newFile.Append(line + "\r\n");

                    replacementMade = true;

                  //  break;

                }
                if (!replacementMade)
                {
                    File.WriteAllText(@"D:\madhu\test2\23.txt", newFile.ToString());
                }

            }
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: whats the question here?

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty clear: you need to move the declaration of `StringHelpers` out of the `Form1` class (most likely in a new file `StringHelpers.cs`).

NB: a "nested" class is a class "inside" another class, it's not allowed for extension methods.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message suggests: *"Extension methods must be defined in a top level static class; StringHelpers is a nested class*: `Form1`.

```
namespace Figreplace2
{  
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        // get it out of this class
    }

    public static class StringHelpers
    {
        public static string Replace(this string s)
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your entire `StringHelpers` `Replace` method is messed up.

what's `file`, `temp`, `newFile`?

they are used but not defined