# Replace in Html file

Tags: c#

I am using following code. It displays only HTML file in  list box 
I want to replace Figure 1, Figure 1.2, Figure 2, Figure 2.1 so on .......
with Figure 1 ........... in OutPut

please help me

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(textBox1.Text);
        StreamReader stRead = file.OpenText();
        while (!stRead.EndOfStream)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(stRead.ReadLine());
        }
    }
}
```

output

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<p class="epigraph"> very Figure 1 But thanks to you, we won&#x0027;t do it </p>
<p class="epigraph-right"> birthday Figure 1.1  Milton Friedman, November 8, 2002</p>
<p class="indent">Not Figure 2 able to take it any longer New York </p>
<p class="indent">Mr. Cutler Figure 2.1 of the parallel plunges</p>
</body>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: `String.Replace(string, string)` MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx)

Comment: @Liam In general, replacement in dom is not that easy.

Comment: @Leri He's reading it as a string `strRead.ReadLine()`. If that string contains HTML or not is irrelevant.

Comment: You can use [Regex.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace.aspx) assuming the ' Figure #.#' can vary.

Comment: @Liam That's why I added _in general_ at the beginning. I stop reading questions here whenever I see: _pls_, _help me, [any variation "please" here]_, _it's urgent_, etc. :)

Comment: Also, please **stop asking the same question multiple times** [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18739527/replace-id1-value1-with-id1-newvalue1) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18739943/replace-figure-1-with-reference-link)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to test that

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(textBox1.Text);
StreamReader stRead = file.OpenText();
while (!stRead.EndOfStream)
{
    string strTemp = stRead.ReadLine();
    for (int i = 1; i < MaxFigureCount; i++)
        strTemp = strTemp.replace("Figure "+i+" ", "Figure "+i+".x ");
    listBox1.Items.Add(strTemp);
}
```

as you can see I do not know your `MaxFigureCount` also I have `".x"` as I cannot figure out what you are trying to do.

also I have extra space at the end to make sure we do not miss with 2.1 or 1.2 if they already exist.

Comment: Error Found : 'string' does not contain a definition for 'replace' and no extension method 'replace' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found

Comment: @user2753776 Maybe read the documentation (that several people have posted) for **Replace**? or check the intelli-sense in VS? A bit of independent thought can go a long way

Comment: It needs to start with capital R, I did write that up on my iPad :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [String.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx)

```
while (!stRead.EndOfStream)
{
    string test = stRead.ReadLine();
    string correctString = test.Replace("Figure 1", " Figure 1.2");
    //Etc. etc.....
    listBox1.Items.Add(correctString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with Regex.Replace:

```
listBox1.Items.Add(Regex.Replace(stRead.ReadLine(), @"\sFigure \d+.\d+\s", " Figure 1 "));
```

I've done some test and apparently work fine, but i'm not an expert of regex syntax.